# One month old Samsung Series 5 Ultrabook (Windows 8) giving low memory warning, and google chrome crashes

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, memory, ultrabook

I have no idea about computers, but I know my laptop shouldn't be using 92% of it's memory when all I have open is google chrome and itunes, I have run anti-virus software so there is no virus causing the problem. I would greatly appreciate some help on how to fix this problem as I am struggling to find any information anywhere.

google chrome - 256MB
symantec service - 90MB 
service host local system - 60MB 
windows explorer - 32MB

etc.

nothing seems to be using a significantly large amount of memory

Comment: There is no (direct) correlation between the age of a computer, and the memory contention. What amount of RAM does the PC have?

Comment: Chrome is a memory hog and the more tabs you have open, the more RAM your laptop will use.

Comment: @yassarikhan786 While that is true, I have 2gigs (very low amount these days), and I can get along with some dozens of them open, plus Eclipse instances, and whatnot...

Comment: Depends on the content on the sites as well I think. I have 10 tabs open, each consuming 90+ MB.

Comment: Look in Task Manager and see what's using up all your RAM. It's not that hard.

Comment: Provide information on what is using your memory 6GB is more the enough for hundreds of Chrome tabs

Comment: @allquixotic I don't know what all the programs are for and if the computer needs them or not? (sorry but I am useless with these things)

Comment: You also may want to look into how much memory is being used by your active antivirus suite when the PC is idle. The reason why many in the IT community tend to shy away from Norton or McAfee is because they tend to slow things down worse than a virus would!

Comment: There is nothing in particular using a significant amount of memory

Comment: post pictures of the Taskmgr (Performance/Memory tab)

Comment: Since you mentioned Windows 8 - Run Resource Monitor (windows + R -> resmon) and check under Memory and see what are the processes eating up your memory. In my PC - the biggest memory hog is Chrome (yes it is turning into old firefox when they had memory leak issue) - and there is MULTIPLE processes for Chrome (depends on how many tabs you got open) and they eat up lots of your RAM... very very VERY quickly. Mind you iTunes and Anti Virus can easily eat up a fair bit as well.

Comment: -1 You are making no sense at all. If an analysis program shows you are using 92% of memory, then it should also show the breakdown. Provide screenshots showing 92% and showing the minimal usage by your programs. And in task manager sort by amount of memory used. It seems like you're not properly reading the output your program is showing you

Answer (score 0):

On the start screen, search for 'services' and click on 'View local services'. Scroll down and see if you can find 'IntelliMemory'. Right click it, and press stop, the right click again and press properties. In the Startup type drop-down box, choose 'disabled'. Then restart your laptop.

If that works then you can uninstall it. The worst bloatware I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Paging File limit, instead of allowing system to do so automatically.  I think that was what was eating up my memory.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how to do that?  Thanks.